# Can I access a WCF service from another pc on ionic view

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi I want to test my app on a device using `ionic view` but my database is on another pc running a web service. I want to know if it is possible to connect to that service from `ionic view`. On my browser (`ionic serve`) I am struggling with CORS issues would that be the same issue running on ionic view?

**Html Code**

```
<ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <div class="list card">
            <div class="item item-divider">Recent Updates</div>
            <div class="item item-body">
                <div>
                    <b>sector 3</b>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list card">
            <div class="item item-divider">Upcoming</div>
            <div class="item item-body">
                <p>{{Success + " " + Error}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get("http://192.168.1.108/TruckService.svc?singleWsdl")
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.Success = "SUCCESS!";
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            $scope.Error = "ERROR dude!";
        });
})

.controller('ChatsCtrl', function($scope, Chats) {

    $scope.chats = Chats.all();
    $scope.remove = function(chat) {
        Chats.remove(chat);
    };
})

.controller('ChatDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Chats) {
    $scope.chat = Chats.get($stateParams.chatId);
})

.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.settings = {
        enableFriends: true
    };
});
```

Comment: make it http://192.168.1.108/TruckService.svc?singleWsdl restful web service and use it

Comment: It now shows : `http://localhost:8100/192.168.1.108/TruckService.svc?singleWsdl Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` this error in my browsers console log.  @sport

Comment: This also shows after that error : `XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8100/192.168.1.108/TruckService.svc?singleWsdl".` @sport